# Getting " error: Potentially incompatible change required to top-level dependency" error on meteor project

Tags: meteor, package

I am getting the following error message when I try to launch my Meteor project

```
=> Errors prevented startup:                  

   While selecting package versions:
   error: Potentially incompatible change required to top-level dependency: joshowens:accounts-entry 0.7.3, was 1.0.4.
   Constraints on package "joshowens:accounts-entry":

   To allow potentially incompatible changes to top-level dependencies, you must pass --allow-incompatible-update on the command line.

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Ive tried removing the package and updating/downgrading it but I cannot resolve this error or figure out how to run the "-allow-incompatible-update on the command line." command. Any Suggestions?

Comment: I don't know about the problem but you can try updating using `meteor update --allow-incompatible-update`. If that doesn't work, you can also give `meteor --allow-incompatible-update` a try just to verify.

Comment: Not to necro an old topic, but I ran across this as well recently as a result of using `meteor update --patch` to go from pre 1.4.4.3 to 1.4.4.3.  I was a little unsure about potential side effects of using the `allow-incompatible-update` flag; I wouldn't mind a little more detail on why it's the recommended fix.  For me, using `meteor update` and `meteor update --all-packages` to switch to the most recent version (1.5.1) resolved the problems for me without breaking any existing functionality.  YMMV.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `meteor --allow-incompatible-update` and the error message is gone.

Comment: Thanks! Embarrassing enough, when I tried this I misspelled it.